# OSM server tiles and Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, installation, api, overpass-api

I'm a beginner in Openstreetmap, and I have some questions I didn't find answer yet.

I created my own server tile through this tutorial: 
https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/

Now, I need to do some queries locally, but I noticed that overpass api have a installation, and in its tutorial has the following description: 
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation

> NOTE: You do not need a database engine (e.g. MySQL or PostgreSQL); the database back-end is included in the OSM3S package.

So, I have my own server tile running, do I need run this full installation? Or is there a way to I use overpass search from my Postgres (postgis) database?

I'm little confused because it has its own database (overpass)(?) according to main description.

In summary: Make it some sense I run queries from my own tile server database, or I need install overpass database and run queries on overpass api database and so plot on my tile server?

If it is possible, someone has some tutorial to indicate me?

Comment: Which kind of queries do you want to run in the first place? SQL? Overpass QL?

Answer (score 2):

Overpass API needs its very own database because it has to perform very different queries compared to a tile server. Likewise if you intend to set up a geocoder (e.g. Nominatim) you will also need a different database for the very same reasons.

It's all about performance optimization. Usually these services are deployed on different physical systems so that's not a problem. Theoretically it would be possible to use a single database for all services but that would be horribly slow.